# Jpa Database relationships for a Voting system

Tags: jpa, playframework, relationship, voting-system

There are many questions about voting systems so I will cut right to the chase.

My question is about relationships ,

```
import play.db.jpa.GenericModel;

public class VotesModel extends GenericModel {
    @ManyToOne
    public StatusModel status;
    @ManyToOne
    public UserModel user;
    public Date time;
}
```

The usual voting rules apply,

1. A status can have many votes
2. A user can vote on many status.
3. But a user can vote only once on a status .

I have easily applied the first 2 rules as `@ManyToOne` , How do I apply the 3rd and most important rule?

Environment:

Playframework `1.2.5` , MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a composite key out of `status` and `user`

Comment: I found the answer with your help, but please update the answer with some code on creating a compound/composite key so that I can accept your answer .

Comment: http://www.google.es/search?q=jpa+composite+id&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:es-ES:official&client=firefox-a&safe=strict

Comment: I found that and solved the issue , Can you please add the details to your answer so that its complete and I can accept it .

Comment: Why should there be code in the answer? There are a lot of examples one can find using Google or the search engine on stackoverflow. The web doesn't need another one. For you the answer worked so why not accept it?